# ScheduleExpression for every 40 days?

Tags: ejb-3.0

How can I declare a timer which is invoked every x days? For example, I want to invoke the timer every 40 days. How should I setup my timer? I cannot convert "40 days" to hours as hours expects a range between 0-23. I cannot put 40 days in dayOfMonth as it expects a range between 1 to 31. So how should I do that?

```
ScheduleExpression expression = new ScheduleExpression();
expression.second("0").minute("0").hour("0").dayOfMonth("40");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below method of `TimerService` interface to create a interval timer, that will expire every 40 days by specifying that duration as `intervalDuration` after  initialization of it by `initialDuration` in milliseconds.

`createTimer(long initialDuration, long intervalDuration, java.io.Serializable info) 
          Create an interval timer whose first expiration occurs after a specified duration, and whose subsequent expirations occur after a specified interval.`